# JSON response in CakePHP taking incorrect value

Tags: php, arrays, json, cakephp

I'm trying to make a cakephp app where I'm trying to receive an array through JSON POST request, save it in a local array in controller and pass that array to json view where it can just give a json response with the same array.
I've added mapresources and parseextensions in routers.php. It's giving me a 200ok response on hitting it with a POST Json request but it's not saving the data in local array, and also it's passing a whole html page appended with the json response.
This is my controller:

```
class UsersController extends AppController{

    public $components = array('RequestHandler');    
    public function index(){
     }

    public function add(){    
        if($this->request->is('post')){
       $data = $this->User->save($this->request->data);
                $this->set(array(
                'data' => $data,
                '_serialize' => array('data')
            ));
    }}}
```

I named json view file add.ctp. This is JSON view in /app/view/Users/JSON/add.ctp :

```
<?php
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

My table Users originally saves userdata in the form of name, password email etc. What's happening is when I'm hitting url /localhost/FC/app/users.json with following data {{"firstname":"abcrehd","lastname":"sdfsdf"}
It's basically storing data in the users table instead of saving it in local array and the passing the user data+other empty columns as json response appended with a long html page.  My questions are:
 1. How do I just store the json response in local array?
 2. How do I pass that array to json view?
 3. How do I receive back that array in just json response?

Please help me out. I've been stuck on this forever! thanks :)

Comment: When using _serialize, do you really still need the view ctp? The Json View class would not need it and can do the same without the view file overhead - see http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html

Comment: Even if i don't use serialize, the output is the same...how can I save a json post request in an array?

Comment: You misunderstood. I was not saying you should not use it. I was saying if you use it you dont also need the view. The _serialize - as documented - itself suffices.

Comment: Oh...but in any case, does deleting the view solve the problem? What do I add in the controller in place of the view?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out with help from the good people above me who led me to the answer:

```
$data=$this->request->input('json_decode');
```

This saves the post json request into a variable called $data.

```
$this->set(array(
                          'data' => $data,
              '_serialize' => array('data')));
```

As mark pointed out above, you don't need a view in layouts or view/json etc... serialize is enough for that.The above code will send back a json response if you use the standard cakephp format of postin in the url with .json suffixed and making the method name add()

Thank you for the help guys!

Answer (score -1):

If i understood well:

```
public function add(){
if($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('ajax')){
    if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
                 $this->layout='Ajax' ;
                 /* another actions ..... */
                 $this->set(data,$this->request->data) ; // it's no need i think it will be accessible in view!
                 $this->render('jasonView') ;
    }
}
}
```